# Video causes Firefox to lag?

Tags: html, css, firefox, video

So one page of my website is quite video heavy. It has a big one as the background and like ~4 small ones in boxes. In Chrome this works wonderful and without any problems. But in Firefox its laggy and makes the entire interface frustrating to work with.
Now, I suspect this might be due to the fact that Firefox doesn't use the GPU, but im of course not sure, it could also be the code.

Im using mp4 videos. This is the code:

```css
.video {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: -1;
opacity:0.2;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<video loop muted autoplay poser="bootstrap/img/lp_header.png" class="video">
<source src="bootstrap/video/game_hub_bg2.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Comment: `I suspect this might be due to the fact that Firefox doesn't use the GPU`. You're wrong. Go to Options > Advanced > General > Browsing > Check(Tick) "Use hardware acceleration when available".

Comment: Consider replacing your videos with image placeholders that are dynamically replaced with video once clicked.

Comment: The exact properties on hardware acceleration depend on the OS, firefox version, available hardware and some experimental switches in about:config. AIUI there are some optimizations for opaque layers. So setting an opacity value other than 1 might be what's causing it.

Answer (score -2):

There is **not** a code-able solution to this, however there are some alternatives.

1. Decrease your file size, using Javascript you can call a lower quality video on firefox (not going to provide an example since that's not what the question has asked).
2. Restrict your website for chrome use, this is a code-able solution.
3. Get a better computer.
4. Enable Firefox to use the GPU by hovering Options > Advanced > General > Browsing > Enable Tick. (@Marcos Perez Gude in the comments provided this alternative, shoutout to you).

Comment: "*Restrict your website for chrome use, this is a code-able solution.*" - that's fairly user-hostile advise to give. Didn't you learn anything from the **"Works best on IE6"** times?